# Generate layered binscatter plots in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, scatter-plot

I want to generate binned scatterplots in R:

I have written the Stata code:

```
binscatter c b a , nquantiles(20) ///
    mcolor(black) ///
    ylabel(, nogrid) ///
    ytitle("") ///
    xtitle("title") ///
```

Is it possible to add another binsreg in the same picture, such that one have two lines for two different data?

So far I did the following:

```
binsreg(df1$b, df1$a, line = c(3,3))
```

The following I want to put over the first one:

```
binsreg(df1$c, df1$a, line = c(3,3))
```

Comment: Have you deleted the question from yesterday? I looked around and I found nothing to combine two binned scatterplots within the `binsreg` package. But I am not sure. Colud you provide the example df?

Comment: @TarJae there is the `by` argument, which allows groups to be defined, though this means pivoting to long format (see below)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible to have two or more different series, since you can use the `by` argument to define a grouping variable. However, that means your data needs to be pivoted into long format, so that instead of having two columns "b" and "c", you have one column for the value and one column denoting which column the value originally came from. This is trivial to do using `tidyr::pivot_longer`.

To demonstrate, we need some sample data. Since you didn't supply any in your question, here is a trivial example with the same names as your own data:

```r
set.seed(1)
df1 <- data.frame(a = rnorm(100), b = rnorm(100), c = rnorm(100))
```

Now we draw the two plots for b and c using your own code:

```r
library(binsreg)

binsreg(df1$c, df1$a, line = c(3,3))
```

[image]

```r
binsreg(df1$b, df1$a, line = c(3,3))
```

[image]

To combine these into a dingle plot, we create a long-format data frame like this:

```r
df2 <- tidyr::pivot_longer(df1, -a)
```

Now we can use the `by` argument and the `bycolors` argument to create lines with whichever colors we deem best:

```r
binsreg(df2$value, df2$a, line = c(3, 3), 
        by = df2$name, bycolors = c("red3", "blue3"))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-07-23 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>